# neuralnet in R always produces the same result

Tags: r, neural-network

I created a simple neural network. The issue is whatever I done for my network it classifies things perfectly.Always get accuracy, sensitivity, specificity as 1.

I need to know that I have made something wrong

following is my code.

```
#maxs <- apply(new_columns, 2, max) 
#mins <- apply(new_columns, 2, min)

#scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(new_columns, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))

#train_ <- scaled[index,]
#test_ <- scaled[-index,]

# Notice the coercion happens before doing anything else.
#.new_columns <- new_columns %>% mutate(yyes = as.factor(yyes))

set.seed(3033)
intrain <- createDataPartition(y = new_columns$yyes, p= 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_ <- new_columns[intrain,]
test_ <- new_columns[-intrain,]


n <- names(train_)
f <- as.formula(paste("yyes ~", paste(n[!n %in% "yyes"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train_,hidden=c(3,2),algorithm = "rprop+",threshold=0.1,stepmax = 1e+06)

pr.nn <- compute(nn,test_)

pr.nn_ <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(new_columns$yyes)-min(new_columns$yyes))+min(new_columns$yyes)
test.r <- (test_$yyes)*(max(new_columns$yyes)-min(new_columns$yyes))+min(new_columns$yyes)
test_pred_binary_neu <- +(pr.nn_ >= 0.5)

MSE.nn <- sum((test.r - pr.nn_)^2)/nrow(test_)

caret::confusionMatrix(factor(test_pred_binary_neu),factor(test.r))

summary(new_columns)

xtab_neu <- table(test_pred_binary_neu, test.r)
confusionMatrix(xtab_neu, positive = "1")
```

Kindly help to to sort this.

following are my statistic results

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neural nets overfit!!!

Comment: What I can do to fix this. Can you kindly help

Comment: You can set priors over parameters and also try regularization. It depends of how many vars you have ! Also I would recommend `h2o` package for neural nets!

Comment: @Duck; if this was overfitting would it not be expected that the results on the test set would be poor (as compared to on the train).  user3789200; could it be that you  are passing the outcome in the test data or that one predictor gives perfect prediction?

Comment: Yes that's wt I was thinking of too.. But as I understood, I am passing the values correctly.